# use bjt or mosfet in h-bridge with inductive load?

Tags: mosfet, bjt, h-bridge

is it better to use 2 pnp bjt in high side and 2 npn bjt in low side of an  inductive load drive h-bridge ?

or using 2 pmos in high side and 2 nmos in low side of h-bridge?

what are the advantages and disadvantages of using each one ?

if our system is intended to drive a particular inductive load continuously for 10 years with switching frequency below 50Hz, which one seems to be more reliable and durable?

Comment: Conventional bipolar transistors are basically unheard of in modern bridges.  Most designs are MOSFET, possibly IGBTs at high voltage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton BJTs aren't "basically unheard of" in this application space. Many hobbyist books talk about them for discrete use. And one common half-bridge is the [UC2950T](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slus280a/slus280a.pdf), for example. There's a narrow range of applications where BJTs are better. That said, broadly speaking, I agree. I just don't think BJTs are to be entirely disparaged as a "modern" vs "olden days" thing. Specific situations push one way or another. No panaceas exists yet.

Comment: It's the huge losses - shown in your own link - that make BJT's obsolete in low voltage applications.  Hobbyists who use them do so from ignorance - they read a tutorial that mentions a 30 year old bipolar part and run with it, then wonder why their motor that works fine on a particular cell count without the bridge, barely turns with it.

Answer (score 1):

When you've chosen particular BJTs or FETs that are specified to take your particular current and voltage, there will be little difference in their expected reliability and durability.

What *will* make a difference is your design, and your implementation of that design in hardware.

An inductive load will require clamping, otherwise it can produce large voltage transients. Generally, FETs have a parasitic diode inside which also tends to be specified to be suitable for clamping. But check. BJTs will need an external clamping diode. Make sure the clamp is close enough to the BJTs to be effective, the inductance of long wires can allow higher transients than you expect.

The devices will require proper heatsinking. Make sure the interfaces, device to heatsink, are sound and durable.

Turn them on and off fast enough (needs a well designed base/gate driver) so that transient dissipation is minimised, but not too fast, so that voltage transient generation is minimised.

You might want to consider IGBTs instead of BJTs, at least at higher voltages where the saturation voltage is less of an efficiency hit. They are effectively BJTs without the steady base current requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure it's quite right to say FETs "are built with" a parasitic diode; the parasitic diode just kind of happens as a consequence of making the FET. "built with" implies that it's put there on purpose (which, in some power FETs, there is a second diode put there intentionally, but then it's not parasitic).